# Subscription a list of item in pdf to users

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf

Is there any way send a pd f list each month to someone user please ? in asp.net i'm searching for that without having an answer can someone help please?

Comment: your requirement is not clear. Try to explain.

Comment: @voddy yes i want to send a list of product to each user on my website every month , in pdf

Answer (score 0):

These would be the steps. Research on how to do them correctly

- create a PDF and write your product list on to it.you'll have to use iTextSharp libraries like iTextSharp.text,iTextSharp.text.pdf.

eg:to give you a head start

```
Dim prodlist = new Document()
Dim strm = new new FileStream(yourpath & "Products.pdf", FileMode.Create)
PdfWriter.GetInstance(prodlist, strm)
myDocument.Open()
myDocument.Add(new Paragraph("product list for January"))
```

Iterate your product list and write it on to the PDF. There are loads of articles online on how to format and style your document.

- Next step is to generate a mail and attach your document. Read this article for that

[system.net.mail](http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/3.4.1.aspx)

I hope this is enough to get you started.